# Android google map crashes

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I had my google maps working on my app before. Now I have added the code to get from my php server and now it is crashing and I have no clue why. I have made sure that the JSON is correct. What it is suppose to do is contact my server, get a list of locations and input them on the map with markers. I have also tried to do this in Async but after searching found i can't change the UI from the background.

MY MAP.JAVA

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnInfoWindowClickListener 
{    
   private GoogleMap map;
   private int zoomLevel = 10;
   static JSONObject object =null;

// flag for Internet connection status
   Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

    // Connection detector class
    Connection cd;

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mapnav, menu);
        return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{       
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.action_add:
        // Single menu item is selected do something
        // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
        Toast.makeText(this, "Add place is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent A = new Intent(this, Add.class);
        startActivity(A);
        return true;

    case R.id.action_events:
        // Single menu item is selected do something
        // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
        Toast.makeText(this, "Events is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent E = new Intent(this, Events.class);
        startActivity(E);
        return true;

    case R.id.action_map:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Map is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent M = new Intent(this, Map.class);
        startActivity(M);
        return true;

    case R.id.action_chat:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Chat is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent c = new Intent(this, Chat.class);
        startActivity(c);
        return true;

    case R.id.action_settings:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Settings is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}    

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);

    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    String json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://www.mywebsite.com/test.json");

    if (json != null) 
    {
        try 
        {
            JSONObject parent = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray eventDetails = parent.getJSONArray("maps");

            for(int i=0; i < eventDetails.length(); i++)
            {
                object = eventDetails.getJSONObject(i);

                String getName = object.getString("name");
                String getAddy =object.getString("addy");
                String getHours = object.getString("hours");
                String getDesc = object.getString("desc");
                String getLat = object.getString("lat");
                String getLong = object.getString("long");

                Log.e("JSON", "> " + getName + getAddy + getHours + getDesc + getLat + getLong );

                // creating connection detector class instance
                cd = new Connection(getApplicationContext());

                try 
                {
                    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

                    // Get name of best provider
                    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

                    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                                .getMap();

                    if (map!=null)
                    {
                       map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                       map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
                       map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                       // My current location
                       Location myloc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                       // Get latitude of current location
                       double latitude = myloc.getLatitude();
                       // Get longitude of current location
                       double longitude = myloc.getLongitude();

                       double lat = Double.valueOf(getLat);
                       double lng = Double.valueOf(getLong);

                       // create latlng
                       LatLng mylocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                       // Move the camera instantly to defaultLatLng.
                       map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mylocation, zoomLevel));

                       LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                       map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location)
                                .title(getName)
                                .snippet(getHours)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                        .fromResource(R.drawable.icon)));

                      // map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
                     }
                }
                catch (NullPointerException e) 
                {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
           }
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Json Error", "Error: " + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        // Setting alert dialog icon
        alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Navigation.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

  @Override
   public void onPause() 
   {
                if (map != null)
                {
                                map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
                                map.setTrafficEnabled(false);
                }
                super.onPause();
   }

   @Override
   public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) 
   {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Map_layout.class);
                intent.putExtra("snippet", marker.getSnippet());
                intent.putExtra("title", marker.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("position", marker.getPosition());
                startActivity(intent);
   }

   private class PrefetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
   {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            super.onPreExecute();    
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
        {
            return null;
        }
      }  
}
```

MY LOGCAT

```
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482): Process: com.databasedemo, PID: 7482
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.databasedemo/com.databasedemo.Map}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnec tionOperator.java:137)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at com.databasedemo.JsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(JsonParser.java:35)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at com.databasedemo.Map.onCreate(Map.java:97)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
01-25 18:46:36.142: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     ... 11 more
```

// EDIT FOR RUNNING IN BACKGROUND...

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnInfoWindowClickListener 
{    
   private GoogleMap map;
   private int zoomLevel = 10;
   static JSONObject object =null;

// flag for Internet connection status
   Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

    // Connection detector class
    Connection cd;

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mapnav, menu);
        return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{       
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.action_add:
        // Single menu item is selected do something
        // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
        Toast.makeText(this, "Add place is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent A = new Intent(this, Add.class);
        startActivity(A);
        return true;

    case R.id.action_events:
        // Single menu item is selected do something
        // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
        Toast.makeText(this, "Events is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent E = new Intent(this, Events.class);
        startActivity(E);
        return true;

    case R.id.action_map:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Map is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent M = new Intent(this, Map.class);
        startActivity(M);
        return true;

    case R.id.action_chat:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Chat is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent c = new Intent(this, Chat.class);
        startActivity(c);
        return true;

    case R.id.action_settings:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Settings is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}    

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);
    new PrefetchData().execute();
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        // Setting alert dialog icon
        alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Navigation.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

  @Override
   public void onPause() 
   {
                if (map != null)
                {
                                map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
                                map.setTrafficEnabled(false);
                }
                super.onPause();
   }

   @Override
   public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) 
   {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Map_layout.class);
                intent.putExtra("snippet", marker.getSnippet());
                intent.putExtra("title", marker.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("position", marker.getPosition());
                startActivity(intent);
   }

   private class PrefetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
   {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            super.onPreExecute();    
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
        {
            JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
            String json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://www.mywebsite.com/test.json");

            if (json != null) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    JSONObject parent = new JSONObject(json);
                    JSONArray eventDetails = parent.getJSONArray("maps");

                    for(int i=0; i < eventDetails.length(); i++)
                    {
                        object = eventDetails.getJSONObject(i);

                        String getName = object.getString("name");
                        String getAddy =object.getString("addy");
                        String getHours = object.getString("hours");
                        String getDesc = object.getString("desc");
                        String getLat = object.getString("lat");
                        String getLong = object.getString("long");

                        Log.e("JSON", "> " + getName + getAddy + getHours + getDesc + getLat + getLong );

                        // creating connection detector class instance
                        cd = new Connection(getApplicationContext());

                        try 
                        {
                            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

                            // Get name of best provider
                            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

                            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                                        .getMap();

                            if (map!=null)
                            {
                               map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                               map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
                               map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                               // My current location
                               Location myloc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                               // Get latitude of current location
                               double latitude = myloc.getLatitude();
                               // Get longitude of current location
                               double longitude = myloc.getLongitude();

                               double lat = Double.valueOf(getLat);
                               double lng = Double.valueOf(getLong);

                               // create latlng
                               LatLng mylocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                               // Move the camera instantly to defaultLatLng.
                               map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mylocation, zoomLevel));

                               LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                               map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location)
                                        .title(getName)
                                        .snippet(getHours)
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                                .fromResource(R.drawable.icon)));

                              // map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
                             }
                        }
                        catch (NullPointerException e) 
                        {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                      }
                   }
                catch (JSONException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.e("Json Error", "Error: " + e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
            return null;
         }
      }  
}
```

// LOG CAT FOR RUNNING IN BACKGROUND

```
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593): Process: com.databasedemo, PID: 7593
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at maps.aq.o.b(Unknown Source)
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at maps.ak.g.b(Unknown Source)
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at maps.af.al.k(Unknown Source)
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at clz.onTransact(SourceFile:304)
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.getUiSettings(Unknown Source)
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.getUiSettings(Unknown Source)
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at com.databasedemo.Map$PrefetchData.doInBackground(Map.java:198)
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at com.databasedemo.Map$PrefetchData.doInBackground(Map.java:1)
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-25 18:58:20.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do this is with an AsyncTask, as mentioned. There are 3 key components to an AsyncTask, you'll need two of them. The third is progress, which it doesn't seem like you'll need, as you're only making one network call. The two you will use are:

- `doInBackground`- This is where stuff that takes a long time, like Network Operations, should happen. Usually you'll find something from here to pass on to the main thread, like a Bitmap or a String, or maybe even something else entirely.
- `onPostExecute`- This is where the UI stuff goes. Android only allows one thread to access the UI, all other threads must pass stuff to the UI thread to do work, or operate on the UI. It turns out onPostExecute is always run on the UI thread.

All you need to do is figure out which piece of this is network connection, and which piece is UI operations, and what needs to flow between them to make it work. The [Android API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) show an example of how to make this work.

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.databasedemo/com.databasedemo.Map}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

You are running a network operation on the UI `Thread`. Since API 11 you can no longer have long running tasks on the UI `Thread`. You do have an `AsyncTask`, but you are not using it.

In your updated question, you are using an `AsyncTask`, but you are trying to manipulate UI elements from a background `Thread`. You should use `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute()` to update the UI.

Comment: But when I put it on the background in AsyncTask I also get errors. Let me run it in background and will post that log cat.

Comment: That is because you need to learn how to implement `AsyncTask` correctly.

Comment: Network ops in doInBackground, UI in PostExecute. Figure out what needs to pass between the two to make it work right.